# Windows 8.1 onto ubuntu pc with laptop

Tags: boot, dual-boot, usb, windows-8

how do i get windows 8.1 to boot on my new pc? i have a windows 7 laptop, a windows 8.1 64bit key, a usb for a boot drive, and an iso download link. the pc im putting it on already has ubuntu installed. when i treid using a media creation tool provided by windows, it started downloading it straight to my laptop without letting me choose to add it to the usb! i also have a dvd burner.

Answer (score 0):

After the Windows installation has finished, you won't be able to access the Ubuntu partition. You will need to rerun grub from a live disk to create a new grub menu. The windows install will (probably) overwrite the existing grub. I can't remember the exact procedure, but search for 'repair grub config' on the web and you should find a how-to (probably on Ask Ubuntu site! )

Comment: thank you i will do that, but my initial question is still unanswered...i cant a seem to get a bootable drive made for my fresh pc.

Comment: Ah. Apologies - I mis-read the question. I don't use Windows these days much, so I'm afraid I don't know the answer: Maybe it has to be downloaded first to 'hard' media before writing to removable media (usb, disc)? Some media creation tools can be a bit 'funny' about writing from an online source (or could, at least - I haven't used those for a while either). Hope someone can help you out soon :-)